# Emacs Jedi python tool unable to load "error searching for program: permission denied, python"?

Tags: python, emacs, elisp, path-variables, python-jedi

I get the following error when I try to open a python file in emacs:

> can’t guess python indent offset, using defaults: 4
>
> deferred error: (error searching for program: permission denied,
>   python)

My assumption is that the python environment variable needs to be copied to the **Emacs PATH variable**, because I had to do the same thing for Mac OS X by using bradleywright's [path.el](https://gist.github.com/bradleywright/2046593) script but now I need to do the same thing for **Windows 7**. How can I do this?

### init.el

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/path.el")

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)


(require 'jedi)
(setq jedi:server-command
  (list "C:/Python33/python.exe" jedi:server-script))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)   

(global-auto-complete-mode t)

(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-1.2.0/magit.el")
(require 'magit)

(require 'linum)
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

Comment: As the jedi knights seem being off-line: Looks like a broken Python install rather. Does Python outside Emacs work?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Yes, I installed python 3.3.2 and if I type "python" in the command prompt the python shell works, but if I go to eshell inside emacs the python command does not work.

Comment: CONTRIBUTING.md: If you get something like `deferred error : (error ...)` in your echo
area, most of the time the error is from Jedi (Python library).  Get
traceback following [this instruction][traceback] and see where the
error is from.  If it is from Jedi, send the bug report to its [issue
tracker][jedi-issue].

[troubleshooting]: http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#troubleshooting
[version-info]: http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#jedi:show-version-info
[traceback]: http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#how-to-get-traceback

Comment: you might miss epc: http://python-epc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Open Python and get the full path to Python using `sys.executable`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
```

And then set `jedi:server-command` like this:

```
(setq jedi:server-command
      (list "THE-PATH-YOU-GOT" jedi:server-script))
```

see also: http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#jedi:server-command

Note that you need to install Python modules (i.e., epc and jedi) and they should be importable for this Python.  So make sure that this works in your Python:

```
>>> import epc, jedi
```

Comment: I updated my init.el in the question, am I doing that right? Also, I am able to import epc and jedi and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `jedi:server-command` looks fine.  Did the error message change?  Other thing to check: Can you invoke plain python from Emacs?  What happen when you do `M-! python --version` or `M-! C:/Python33/python.exe --version`?

Answer (score 1):

Look for a "deferred.el". Exist two functions inside which raise that error. Running them under `edebug` should reveal the cause.

Comment: I am new to edebug.  I tried going through each function using C-x C-e but I was too unfamiliar with edebug to figure it out.  Is that what you meant by running edebug?

Comment: @KoreyHinton Yes. BTW running a different auto-completion, it's switched off here normally, as it produces too much distraction. OTOH Emacs provides TAB-completion, dabbrev-expand, abbrev-mode, which for my taste are even more effective. Tiny consolation :)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting* my computer fixed this error:

> deferred error: (error searching for program: permission denied,
>   python)

**This was my first restart since installing Python.*

Everything seems to be working fine now, I still get the `can’t guess python indent offset, using defaults: 4` error but jedi tab-completion is working fine.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions, it certainly helped!